# Derivative of Log of Summation of exponential function (base e)

Tags: derivatives, summation, exponential-function, exponential-sum

A financial formula that I am implementing requires that I find the first derivative of a function to find a local maxima, from scratch. Can someone please help me with finding the first derivative of this function:

$$
f(\theta) = -\log\left(\frac{1}{T}\sum_{t=1}^Te^{\theta r_t}\right)$$

I am able to simplify it to:

$$
f(\theta) = -\log\left( \sum e^{\theta\cdot r_t }\right) + \log (T) 
$$

And then I thought:

$$
f'(\theta) = -\frac{ \sum r_t\cdot e^{\theta\cdot r_t } }{ \sum e^{\theta\cdot r_t } }
$$
But when real numbers are applied, they don't look right. Right sign but not value.

**Update:**
After scouring a few sources of the formula, which are frustratingly all slightly different in some form or representation, and also taking a step back myself, I believe the issue is that theta is actually the variable. It was never expressed this way. I have update the formula to reflect this.

Comment: Pls use mathjax. Check if my edits are correct.

Comment: How did you check that the formulas you listed are not correct?

Comment: Are you sure that you want $f'(t)$ and not $f'(T)$ ? $\sum_{t=1}^Te^{\theta r t}$ is just the sum of a geometric series and $t$ does not appear in it. Or is your formula $\sum_{t=1}^Te^{\theta r_t t}$ ?

Comment: @tpb261 Thank you for the edits. I couldn't find anything that mentioned mathjax, so I resorted to normal text. I used excel to generate values from a sample set of data. The resulting signs were correct but values were wrong and out by several factors.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Ah yes. I just realised that the formula layout in the original article got this wrong. t is the subscript of r. I have edited the question.  Is my derivative right?

Comment: $t$ is not a variable. It is just the summation index running from $1$ to $T$. I am afraid that, as currently set, the problem does not make any sense.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici That explanation certainly helped me focus. I have edited formula. Does it make sense now?

Comment: MathJax is not a  mathematics package. Its similar to Latex, and used to format the formulas etc :). Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: if $\theta$ is the variable, your expressions look ok.

Comment: Thank you for the formula check. The example values that I'm not sure about might be a function of my time axis scaling in Excel. I shall investigate other tools to confirm.